# Reinstall grails plugin from a simple HTTP location

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I installed a plugin using 'grails install-plugin http://blahblah/blah.zip'. The location does not follow the grailsRepo standard or maven standard. It's a simple zip file on a remote server.

How do I configure grails so that it finds the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. You either have to install the plugin in a maven-compatible repo or you'll have to run install-plugin every time you build from scratch.

Comment: you could explode the plugin into your source tree and set grails.plugin.location in `BuildConfig.groovy` but that doesn't directly answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

in grails project directory grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.plugin.location."pluginName"="../path/to/plugin"
```